# second HttpURLConnection for image loading optimization

Tags: android, memory-management, imageview, httprequest, bitmapfactory

I have read that `HttpUrlConnection` sends GET request when connection is made. Also then I can retrieve an instance of `InputStream` to read that resource. Does this mean that whole resource file is downloaded as the connection is made?

What I want to achieve is to set an `ImageView` image to remote image from the web. However my idea is to do this in `memory-friendly way` and calculate `inSampleSize` for `BitmapFactory`. In order to calculate that size - I need `view dimensions` and `remote image dimensions`. Remote image dimensions may be retrieved this vay (basically it should not load an image into memory):

```
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options ();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream (inputStream, null, options);
```

However once read inputStream can not be reused in this case (or can it?). Also `HttpUrlConnection` returns the same instance of `InputStream` which means that if I want to `read an image again` (and load only the size I need using inSampleSize option) - I have to `re-connect`.

I want to be able to load large images, however as I have heard - HTTP requests are slow so is it worth it to send a second request? Also I don't know if the whole image is downloaded anyway even if I am reading only image info for the first time and not loading the whole thing.

If it is not worth it I think the only way will be to copy whole image into memory, get it's dimensions, read only the size I need and finally clean up the memory. Witch would be pretty memory expensive for the short period of time.

Comment: check this library http://square.github.io/picasso/ it does everything you explained and more.

Answer (score 0):

For loading images from remote web use Android Smart Image View..
it Load Images from URLs in memory friendly way

http://loopj.com/android-smart-image-view/